# How can i give 'add_modelname','change_modelname', 'delete_modelname', 'view_modelname' permissions to a group in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django-3.2

I have a model named `Flower` and a group named `mygroup`.
How can i give `'add_flower','change_flower', 'delete_flower', 'view_flower'` permissions to `mygroup` group?

```
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='mygroup')
        if created:
            new_group.save()
        user.groups.add(new_group)
```

I add this code but i get some errors:

```
new_group.permissions.add('add_flower')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_per = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_flower')
change_per = Permission.objects.get(codename='change_flower')
del_per = Permission.objects.get(codename='delete_flower')
view_per = Permission.objects.get(codename='view_flower')
new_group.permissions.add(add_per,change_per,del_per,view_per)
```